# How to check content of commit still exists?

Tags: git, compare, comparison, commit

How can I verify that content from existing commits from e.g. last year is still unchanged?
I have 10 commits with same tag which content maybe lost or overwritten. Now I need to match the current content with that old commits to verify if there a changes or not.

Answer (score 1):

Compare two `commit/branch` and see if there is any difference.

```
$ git fetch
$ git log                           # copy the commit hash

$ git diff HEAD..<commit>           # shows what is in the commit that is not in HEAD   
$ git diff <commit-1> <commit-2>    # diff of two commits
$ git diff <branch-1>..<branch-2>   # diff off two branches
```